# Get browser window size/resolution with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, browser

I have a page that starts with a navigation bar, with specific height, and under that I placed a code that should fill out the rest of the height. How could I code it for various resolutions? I need the "working area" size of the browser.

Comment: Finding the window size is not possible with pure PHP. This needs Javascript - and a lot of results for that are just a Google away: `javascript window size`. What you mention in the title, however, is possible using CSS as @FakeRainBrigand says

Comment: This sounds like it could be done with CSS (if I'm understanding correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot be done with PHP.  Even if it could, [this CSS](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html) is a far better solution.

You have encountered the most annoying CSS problem in existence.  There seems to be as many answers to this question as there are people asking it.  The above link is the best, most cross-browser friendly solution I have found for this issue.

Don't let the part about the footer confuse you.  If you don't want a footer, it will still work perfectly.

Comment: Really great article and demo! +1

Answer (score 7):

`$window_width = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(window.innerWidth);</script>";`

Comment: this is among somethings in the world, which I like, work like a charm

Comment: Is this a standard approach ?

Comment: I downvoted this because it is not a complete answer.  I see some code here, with no reference to where it is to be placed within the PHP, or how it's used.  Without more information, all this code does, is to set a variable named $window_width to a string value that's no more than gibberish.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I did it. I just replaced my index.php with this simple little tool, and renamed my index.php index2.php. It just checks these things using pure javascript and passes them to your real index file as $_GET variables. What could be easier than that? All done! Took me 5 minutes, will take you 30 seconds :)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
            var landscapeOrPortrait = 'portrait';
        } else {
            var landscapeOrPortrait = 'landscape';
        }

        var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;

        var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;



        window.location.replace('index2.php?width='+width+'&height='+height+'&landscapeOrPortrait='+landscapeOrPortrait);            
    </script>            
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning.

```
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: That would not work. Anthing after the fold would still be the `body` colour: http://jsfiddle.net/FeP3b/

Comment: @myhead - who said anything about background color or content extending beyond the fold?  My code causes an element to fill the remaining space in the browser window following a header with fixed height.  Maybe you are assuming too much about the original poster's requirements.

Comment: You are right - that was an assumption, but I believe it to be a fair one. If you were not to apply a background colour or border, then what reason is there to make an element fill the remaining space?